# Partition and bucketing on same column in hive table

Tags: hive

I have data in my hive table which was partitioned by date. As one day data is huge, I want to further divide this data into 4 parts. so that I want to read each part and process the data.

For making one day data into 4 parts, can we use bucketing on same date field and give 4 buckets to make 4 parts?

```
create table state_part(District string,Enrolments string) PARTITIONED BY(enrolled_date string) CLUSTERED BY (enrolled_date) into 4 buckets;
```

I am new to hive and could some one help me to brake this one day data into 4 parts and then read one part of data at a time.

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Babu

Comment: usage scenario is not clear. How are you going to process data? Hive splits big files if they are in splittable format when reading them

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. Basically I have a hive table which was partitioned by hourly. So when I am reading each partition, data is huge and I want to split this single hourly partitioned data to let's say for 20min partition and so it make  into 3 parts and I want to process each part by using spark java code.  I hope you understand the situation and I am looking for help on how we can make this 20min partition with data which we have for 1hour partition.